# Google Apps Admin get a copy of each incoming / outgoing mail in my Inbox

Tags: google-apps

I've a domain and I've successfully configured Email service via Google Apps.
I've created 5 email accounts too.

Now I want to track all the incoming/ outgoing emails.
Is there any way, if any person(among those 5 persons), sends or receives an email, I want a copy of that email in my inbox too automatically.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this question is not about App Engine.

Comment: I re-tagged it to Google Apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure you can receive a copy in another account but you can configure each of the accounts to delegate access to your account so that you can view their sent/received messages. It is more manual than you would like however.

- http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=138350

Answer (score 4):

You can use GAM and Audit monitors to get a copy of a users mail sent and received. You'll also see Chats and Draft messages with an email monitor:

http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-manager/wiki/ExamplesAccountAuditing#Create_a_Audit_Monitor

This feature requires Google Apps for Business or Education.

Jay

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that with out going into the GAM and use the audit, is to configure mail forwarding for each email by going into the gmail account interface.

Another solution that can be used, is to create an external gmail email, and use the google apps email routing to send all the emails to the external one.
On the external one you can just do what ever you want with the email, such as filtering by receiver and forwarding it to your selected destination.

Hope my answer helped a bit.